# PhpStorm autocomplete problem when install node_modules

Tags: autocomplete, ide, phpstorm

PhpStorm autocomplete stopped working when installed `node_modules` in a specific project.

At the same time, in other projects (or in this specific project when `node_modules` is not installed) it works correctly...

The project is a Laravel project.

Comment: If the behavior persists after `Settings/Preferences | Plugins | Installed | [Gear icon] | Disable All Downloaded Plugins` and `File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart`, it makes sense to submit a project sample in a support ticket (`Help | Contact Support`), we'll take a look.

Comment: Did you find a fix to this?

Comment: When I open the phpstorm with cmd from project folder (phpstorm .) it works. but when open phpstorm by click on its icon in aplications list it does not work.